# PyCharm surround with "print"

Tags: pycharm

Pycharm has the function to "surround with" pieces of code. 
There are some already setted up functions:

[image]

I would like to add `print()` (using python3) to it, how can I do?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

AFAIU, you can define your own “Live” templates for this.

#### define the live template

Go to `File`→`Settings`→`Editor`→`Live Templates`. In the right pane tree, click on Python then click the green “+” button on the right; select “Live Template”.

Enter a name for Abbreviation (e.g. “printer”), a Description, and then in the Template text:

```
print($SELECTION$)
```

Afterwards click on the “Define” of the “No applicable contexts. Define” line at the bottom. Select “Python” in the tree. This step is important!

#### use the live template

Now your template will be usable by the `Code`→`Surround with Live Template` action (in my case, the shortcut is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>).

Comment: Can you tell me how mentioned shortcut works.. we have not specified anywhere in the action point right..